# Large File Size Copy Ranges with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a routine that duplicates a sheet by generating cell references to the old sheet. My problem is for that when I run this routine on a three sheets in a workbook sized 280KB it balloons up to 80MB. If I copy and paste the sheet values to remove the formulas, the workbook stays the same size. If I delete the sheets and save then it returns to it's original size. Is there something I'm missing in the way VBA handles memory that is causing this issue? I've already tried setting all of the variables to nothing at the end of the routine.

```
Public Sub CopySheetFormulas(inputSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet)
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim columnCounter As Long
Dim maxRow As Long
Dim maxColumn As Long

maxColumn = inputSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=inputSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

Debug.Print "Max Column: " & maxColumn

maxRow = inputSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=inputSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

Debug.Print "Max Row: " & maxRow

inputSheet.Range("A1").Resize(maxRow, maxColumn).Copy

With outputSheet
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Select
    .Paste Link:=True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: try this `outputSheet.Range("A1").Resize(maxRow,maxColumn).Value = inputSheet.Range("A1").Resize(maxRow, maxColumn)`, in place of the last 6 lines of your code.

Comment: What are the values of maxColumn and maxRow and are they what you would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLSX files store the cell contents as a string. But they don't clean up after themselves very good. So if you delete something, it doesn't always reduce the file size.

If you merely copy the sheet it shouldn't become as big as if you generate links to all the cells. Thats because each link is stored as a separate string.

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelProblems.htm

It's very possible that the original sheet has some modification that reaches to the very last row. Then when you copy it as links it goes crazy because it is generating millions of links. Check the value of maxColumns and maxRows.

Comment: The file is in binary format. I'll take a look at that link.

Comment: You got it! The original file has data in 4 x 10,000 cells but the sheet thought there was data in 10,000 x 10,000. Very odd how empty cells can take up so much memory though.

Comment: Each cell that is modified must be described in the file structure; this makes the file bigger. But then when you generate a link to each of those cells, each link takes up more room. So you get a bloated file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reduce the file size, you need to delete the additional row or column from the sheet, 
then save it. File size will reduce.

For example below snapshot, previously i have 22 records, although i have removed some record, but the empty cells still contributing the file size.
How to know it, CTRL + End, the cell it stop will tell you.

Remove those empty Rows or Columns will reduce file size.

[image]