# Copy large sheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Recently, I encountered a problem which seems to be quite simple to resolve, but I'm new to VBA and due to this I need any advice.
I'm trying to write a macro in VBA which copies a very large sheet (around 140k of lines).

I tried different approaches based on the following topics:

- [Fastest Method to Copy Large Number of Values in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272285/fastest-method-to-copy-large-number-of-values-in-excel-vba)
- [Large File Size Copy Ranges with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079353/large-file-size-copy-ranges-with-vba)
  [Very large excel file - how to copy data between sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466793/very-large-excel-file-how-to-copy-data-between-sheets)

My current solution is:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
With Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    .Sheets(1).Visible = -1
    .Sheets(1).Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)
     wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Name"

    .Close False
End With
```

When I'm running this macros - Excel is not responding and program is not opening the file. My question is, is it any possibility to copy a large sheet using standard VBA methods? The code sample works absolutely fine with smaller files.

Comment: Does the said sheet have lot of formulas? Did you try turning off screenUpdating, Calculation, event handling, etc etc...?

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you for your reply. Yes, I did it.

Comment: Is there something running in FileName also perhaps?

Comment: Could be just a simple matter of not having enough on-board memory to handle the transaction - perhaps there's a lot swap file activity?  Are you using 32 bit Excel?  64-bit will provide better utilization of memory.  I know, I touching on the obvious, and if you're stuck with 32-bit (and limited memory), well, your stuck with 32-bit (and limited memory) :(

Answer (score 0):

Try. It works fine for me.

```
 Sub rten()


 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim docname As String

 docname = "test1"

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With Workbooks.Open(docname, ReadOnly:=True)
        .Sheets(1).Visible = -1
        .Sheets(1).Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)
         wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Name"

        .Close False
    End With


 End Sub
```

It might be because you have a sheet called "Name" that its crashing. Have you checked to see if you already have it there?